# Why was question closed for being primarily opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The intent of my question was to ask if you can improve accuracy for position determination when you have a local atomic clock at hand.

[Can GNSS precision be improved with a local atomic clock?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300176/can-gnss-precision-be-improved-with-a-local-atomic-clock)

Why would this be a question with "primarily opinion-based" answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the redacted timeline for your question the decision to place it On Hold was not unanimous:

[image]

Two reviewers thought that it should be left open (and another has since re-opened it).  Another adjudged that it was not low quality.

Of the five reviewers who voted to close it, one thought it was Too Broad, and the other four thought it Primarily Opinion-based.

Personally, if I were to have taken any action on your very brief question I think it would have been to downvote it for not showing evidence of effort to find an answer prior to posting.  Of the two Close reasons chosen by the reviewers, I think Too Broad would have been the more likely choice, because it falls outside of how I interpret Primarily Opinion-based.